# Is it legal and defined to pass a method reference to a non-overriding derived class method to its base class?

Tags: java, inheritance, method-reference

Is it legal and defined to pass a method reference to a non-overriding derived class method to its base class?

```
public class Base {
   private Supplier<Int> intSupplier;

   public Base(Supplier<Int> intSupplier) { 
        this.intSupplier = intSupplier;
   }

   public Int getInt() { 
        return inSupplier.get(); 
   }
}
```

.

```
public class Derived extends Base {
   public Derived() {
      super(this::returnsOne);
   }

   private Int returnsOne() { return 1; }
}
```

.

```
assert(1 == new Derived().getInt())
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The constructor in the `Derived` class cannot refer to `this` before its super constructor has been called.

Comment: Thanks jrock, that does answer my question. :)

Comment: Not exactly. The code doesn’t compile because you’re trying to create the method reference in the constructor before the super constructor has been called. Since your question doesn’t mention the special case of constructors, the answer is, it would work, if you do it at a different place than before calling the super constructor. And why not? The fact that you’ve implemented the supplier as a call to `returnsOne`, is irrelevant to the code calling the `Supplier`’s `get` method, whether the caller is in a superclass or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do normally ?

```
public class Derived extends Base {

   @Override
   public Int getInt() { 
        returnsOne(); 
   }

   private Int returnsOne() { return 1; }
}
```